# Code to find and concatenate substrings

Tags: javascript

I'm a complete beginner to javascript and am having an issue with a problem I'm trying to solve. The question is:

Complete the `sliceItAndCombineIt` function. This function should:
    - take a string and four indices (numbers)
    - return a new string which is the concatenation of two substrings marked by the first and second index of each pair of indices. For example:

```
sliceItAndCombineIt("This is a Test", 0, 4, 5, 7) // returns "Thisis"
sliceItAndCombineIt("This is a Test", 0, 4, 1, 2) // returns "Thish".
```

```

I was given:

```
module.exports.sliceItAndCombineIt = function(bigString, startA, endA, startB, endB) {
  return 
};
```

This may be dumb, but I really have no idea where to begin. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to get a substring from a string? Do you know how to concatenate strings? Then you know how to solve this.

Comment: look at the substring method on MDN

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very easy to implement:

You need to take 2 sub-strings using the start and end indexes provided, and call concat method on these 2.